# To move from one QML page to another using PyQt

Tags: qt, python-3.x, qml, pyqt4, pyqt5

In fact I am a beginner in QML and PyQt, I found a problem of past from one QML page to another using PyQt then we use QObject (property and setproperty).
So I was able to display the 2nd QML page and then when I use the setproperty I will get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' has no attribute setProperty`.

My second page qml `"Classe.qml"` contains a text field, what I want to do that when I click on the button of my first page `"main.qml"` there will be the second page that appears then the text field Change, we write `"hello world"`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import Classe
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, QVariant



# Classe servant dans l'interaction.
class MainApp(QObject):
   def __init__(self, context, parent=None):
       super(MainApp, self).__init__()

       self.win = parent
       self.win.findChild(QObject, "ObjClasse").clicked.connect(self.test3)

       self.ctx = context

  def test3(self):



    engine.load('Classe.qml')

    self.win.findChild(QObject, "labelCo").setProperty("text", "hello world")         ##l'erreur est ici

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
ctx = engine.rootContext()
engine.load('main.qml')
win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
py_mainapp = MainApp(ctx,win)
ctx.setContextProperty("py_MainApp", py_mainapp)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Don't try to treat qml files as pages. They are classes. Make one main qml  file an use classes from other files in something like a `StackView`, states or `Loaders`. Also, don't try to call `findChild` and `setProperty` from python. The python code should be used by qml as a library of classes: qml can create objects of classes that you implemented in python.

Comment: It's good, it's solved thanks for your help:
In fact it is enough to add a 2nd row in the list rootObject.                                   def test3(self):

        engine.load('Classe.qml')
        win1 = engine.rootObjects()[1]
        win1.findChild(QObject, "labelCo").setProperty("text", "HELLO        WORLD")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's good, it's solved thanks for your help:
In fact it is enough to add a 2nd row in the list rootObject.

```
def test3(self):

    engine.load('Classe.qml')
    win1 = engine.rootObjects()[1]
    win1.findChild(QObject, "labelCo").setProperty("text", "HELLOWORLD")
```